# compare cells in tabs

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, compare, cells

I'm trying to compare cells in 2 tabs (master and test) and if there are changes in test then color changes in any kind of color and copy & paste it to master file.

UPDATED:

Here is required code

```
Sub test()

    Dim varSheetA As Variant
    Dim varSheetB As Variant
    Dim strRangeToCheck As String
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
        Dim jRow As Long
    Dim jCol As Long

    strRangeToCheck = "A1:V1000"
    ' If you know the data will only be in a smaller range, reduce the size of the ranges above.
    Debug.Print Now
    varSheetA = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(strRangeToCheck)
    varSheetB = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(strRangeToCheck) ' or whatever your other sheet is.
    Debug.Print Now

    For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
        For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
            If varSheetB(iRow, iCol) = varSheetA(iRow, iCol) Then
                ' Cells are identical.
                ' Do nothing.
            Else

            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
            Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
            Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 44


            Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            Cells(iRow, iCol).Copy
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
            Cells(iRow, iCol).PasteSpecial xlValues
            Cells(iRow, iCol).PasteSpecial xlFormats

                ' Cells are different.
                ' Code goes here for whatever it is you want to do.
            End If
        Next iCol
    Next iRow
MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you not just use conditional formatting? Maybe I haven't understood the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the last used cell in one of the worksheets.

```
dim lr as long, lc as long

lr= application.max(dWS.cells.specialcells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row, _
                    mWS.cells.specialcells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row)
lc= application.max(dWS.cells.specialcells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column, _
                    mWS.cells.specialcells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column)

For Each c In dWS.Range("A2", dWS.cells(lr, lc))
    If Not dWS.Cells(c.Row, c.Column).Value = mWS.Cells(c.Row, c.Column).Value Then
        dWS.Cells(c.Row, c.Column).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
Next
```

Comment: it says "method or data member not found"

Comment: My bad. SpecialCells is a property of a Range object, not a worksheet.